# iPhone, Stylish Buttons?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to work out (or find) a button that looks half decent for use in my app. In the image below I have two buttons at the bottom, the default button (interfaceBuilder) and one using two png images from the Apple UICatalog.

I am a little shocked that apple did not include something a little more stylish in IB. I assume that my only option is to find/use/make a suitable replacement button image. Before I fire up Photoshop does anyone know of any replacement buttons I might use?

[image]

gary

Comment: I agree. I wish there were built-in styles that were attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try out some button designs, you can draw them in [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/), which includes a template for iPhone buttons.  Opacity can output the button as a stretchable PNG for use in the button or as a UIView / UIButton subclass with all the Quartz drawing calls within it.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use a segmented control with just one segment - you get the shading you want and it's not much harder to use than a standard button.

Comment: (experiment with styles until you get the look you want - try the bar style for something closer to UIButton)

Comment: UISegmentedControl look nice with tint color, but tint color works for the UISegmentedControlStyleBar style.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look into the Three20 library. It provides a `TTButton` class that can be customized using `TTStyle`s, and its very easy to create your own styles. In the Three20 example app, there are a lot of styles available already, especially styles for navigation bar buttons. They serve as great examples.